# Java downloaded file missing 183 bytes

Tags: java, io, gzip

I am trying to download and unzip a file from an FTP server (i.e. ftp://data.ndovloket.nl/netex/arr/NeTEx_ARR_NF_2021-03-01_1431.xml.gz). When downloading this file manually, its size is exactly 6,492,629 bytes. However, when downloading the file using Java, its size is always exactly 6,492,446 bytes, so it seems to be missing 183 bytes every time. Unzipping it then gives an error:

> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid stored block lengths
> at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:165)
> at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(GZIPInputStream.java:118)
> at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
> at me.bys1.netexreader.Main.copyStream(Main.java:170)
> at me.bys1.netexreader.Main.downloadData(Main.java:164)
> at me.bys1.netexreader.Main.main(Main.java:123)

I am using the following code:

```
    private static final void downloadData(final Data data, final File zip, final File file) throws IOException {
        final InputStream inZip = dataManager.getFile(data.path);
        final OutputStream outZip = new FileOutputStream(zip);
        
        copyStream(inZip, outZip);
        final InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(zip));
        final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        copyStream(in, out); //line 146
    }
    
    private static final void copyStream(final InputStream in, final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        /*final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int n;
        while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) out.write(buffer, 0, n);
        in.close();
        out.close();*/ //other code I tried for copying streams, doesn't make any difference
        
        final ReadableByteChannel channelIn = Channels.newChannel(in);
        final WritableByteChannel channelOut = Channels.newChannel(out);
        final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        
        while (channelIn.read(buffer) != -1 || buffer.position() > 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            channelOut.write(buffer);
            buffer.compact();
        }
        
        channelIn.close();
        channelOut.close();
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

Why is the Java download always missing the same amount of data? It does not happen for all files (I tried some smaller files which worked perfectly, while other files gave different unzipping errors). How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you are in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34686162/4017037

Comment: setting the file type to FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE worked. Thanks